# Adding characters to the beginning of an integer

Tags: xslt

How do I add characters to the beginning of an Integer in xslt?

I receive as input 14 and I must return 0014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the format-number function ([XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#format-number), [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#format-number)).